# Comparing groups of different sizes in social network analysis

Tags: group-differences, networks, social-network

I've got social network data for three groups of chimpanzees and I'm looking to do some basic analysis across and between groups. Does anyone by any chance know how to compare social network data between groups (for example, scores of strength from enclosure 1 vs enclosure 2), and/or 2) combine data from different groups (for example, adults from all three groups vs youngsters from all three groups)?

The three chimpanzee groups differ in size (11, 26 and 40), adult/youngster ratio etc. I'm just exploring the data, but I just wondered if/how data can be compared independent of group, because of course social network data output from group 1 cannot be directly/simply compared to group 2, for example. Is there a way to standardize such data. At the moment i'm using SOCPROG for my analysis, but am happy to investigate other approaches if necessary.